# Styling and formatting Pandas dataframes Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, format

I want to display the `numbers` values without any notation like `123242737.49` instead of `1.232427e+08` and I want to place `$` signs intront of all the `Numbers 2` columns. How would I be able to do that and get the Expected output?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([123242737.4923,679754672.3849]) 
numbers2 = np.array([123523,467895]) 

dict_val = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':numbers.round(2),'Numbers 2': numbers2})
display(dict_val)
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

```
    Numbers         Numbers 2
0   123242737.49    $123523
1   679754672.38    $467895
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas's `DataFrame.style`, you can do:

```
dict_val.style.format(formatter={'Numbers': '{:.2f}', 'Numbers 2': '${}'})
```